# Having a minimal constructor while ensuring invariants

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

I recently stumbled upon some code which looked wrong. 
I edited it only to see that my changes broke the code. 
I tried to structure the code in different other ways to make the code both look and be right, but I wasn't satisfied with any alternative I could come up with.

The logic of the code is as follows:

- A `Path` is made of zero or more `Segment`s.
- A `Segment` contains:

  - one or more properties (here only one for brevity), and
  - a reference to the `Path` it is on.
- Invariants that must be upheld:

  - The `Path` reference on a `Segment` is always initialized.
  - A `Segment` is an item of some `Path`'s `Segments`.
  - The `Part` reference on a `Segment` references the `Part`, which `Segments` contain the `Segment`.

Here's the code I looked at, when I thought I had found a bug:

```
public class Path
{
    public List<Segment> Segments { get; } = new List<Segment>();
}

public class Segment
{
    public int Property { get; }

    public Path Path { get; }

    ...
}

public static class Test
{
    public static Path CreatePath()
    {
        var path = new Path();
        var segment = new Segment(path, 42);
        return path;
    }
}
```

By just glimpsing at `CreatePath` and without inspecting further I concluded that there clearly was a bug, since `segment` wasn't added to `path.Segments` and thereby violating an invariant.

Apparently I was wrong as the constructor of `Segment` did more work than I expected.
The actual constructor looked like this:

```
public Segment(Path path, int property)
{
    Property = property;
    Path = path;

    path.Segments.Add(this); // <-- 
}
```

While I acknowledge the intent of the constructor to ensure the invariants, I didn't like the way it was done mainly of two reasons:

- The constructor does more work than validating arguments and initializing fields.
- `CreatePath` only looks correct when you know the internals of the constructor.

This to me breaks the *Principle of Least Astonishment* -- at least I was astonished.

I tried to come up with alternative ways to accomplish this, but I'm not entirely satisfied with any of them.

---

The original code where the consistency is ensured inside the constructor of `Segment`. It's problem is, that `segment` looks unused in `CreatePath` if you don't know about the internals of the constructor.

```
namespace PathExample0
{
    public class Path
    {
        public List<Segment> Segments { get; } = new List<Segment>();
    }

    public class Segment
    {
        public int Property { get; }

        public Path Path { get; }

        public Segment(Path path, int property)
        {
            Property = property;
            Path = path;

            path.Segments.Add(this);
        }
    }

    public static class Test
    {
        public static Path CreatePath()
        {
            var path = new Path();
            var segment = new Segment(path, 42);
            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

---

This first alternative takes out the consistency part of the constructor and into the `CreatePath`. The constructor is now free of surprises and `segment` is clearly used in `CreatePath`.
The minor problem is now, that were are not guaranteed that `segment` is added to `Segments` of the right `Path`.

```
namespace PathExample1
{
    public class Path
    {
        public List<Segment> Segments { get; } = new List<Segment>();
    }

    public class Segment
    {
        public int Property { get; }

        public Path Path { get; }

        public Segment(Path path, int property)
        {
            Property = property;
            Path = path;
        }
    }

    public static class Test
    {
        public static Path CreatePath()
        {
            var path = new Path();
            var segment = new Segment(path, 42);
            path.Segments.Add(segment);
            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

---

My second attempt Adds an `AddSegment` to `Path` which ensures the consistency. 
This still don't hinders you to call `new Segment(somePath, 42)` and break the consistency.

```
namespace PathExample2
{
    public class Path
    {
        private readonly List<Segment> segments = new List<Segment>();

        public IReadOnlyList<Segment> Segments => segments;

        public void AddSegment(int property)
        {
            var segment = new Segment(this, property);
            segments.Add(segment);
        }
    }

    public class Segment
    {
        public int Property { get; }

        public Path Path { get; }

        public Segment(Path path, int property)
        {
            Property = property;
            Path = path;
        }
    }

    public static class Test
    {
        public static Path CreatePath()
        {
            var path = new Path();
            path.AddSegment(42);
            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The third and last example I could come up with interfaces out `Segment` into `ISegment` and makes `Segment` a private class to `Path`. 
This should now ensure full consistency between a `Path` and its `Segment`s.
To me it feel like a cumbersome approach and almost as a misuse of interfaces to hide the constructor of `Segment`.

```
namespace PathExample3
{
    public interface ISegment
    {
        Path Path { get; }

        int Property { get; }
    }

    public class Path
    {
        private readonly List<Segment> segments = new List<Segment>();

        public IReadOnlyList<ISegment> Segments => segments;

        public void AddSegment(int property)
        {
            var segment = new Segment(this, property);
            segments.Add(segment);
        }

        private class Segment : ISegment
        {
            public int Property { get; }

            public Path Path { get; }

            public Segment(Path path, int property)
            {
                Property = property;
                Path = path;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Test
    {
        public static Path CreatePath()
        {
            var path = new Path();
            path.AddSegment(42);
            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

---

So my question is how to structure the code in a way, to ensure the invariants while retaining idiomatic C# code.
Maybe I'm missing out on a well-known design pattern to accomplish this?

Comment: (In my eyes, your question would benefit from an introductory summary where all of it is going to, and a (list of) explicit question(s) at the end.)

Comment: My gut feeling is that the further you separate creating the Segment from adding it to the Path, the more chance for bugs, especially **concurrency** bugs.  But needs more analysis.

Comment: A relevant counterexample to the "constructors must have no side effects" is [SWT graphic widgets,](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html#swt-widgets) which always take a `parent` widget and always add themselves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A way to avoid usage of a misleading constructor is to make it private and instead provide a [static factory method](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA5&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) stating what it does. It also allows you to keep the constructor clean. (I would not say that is has no [side-effect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect). A function changing some state besides returning a value is said to have a side-effect. Since constructors are not functions and cannot return any value, producing side-effects is all they can do. They change the state of the object from uninitialized to initialized.)

```
public class Segment
{
    private Segment(Path path, int property)
    {
        Path = path;
        Property = property;
    }

    public int Property { get; }
    public Path Path { get; }

    public static Segment AddToPath(Path path, int property)
    {
        var segment = new Segment(path, property);
        path.Segments.Add(segment);
        return segment;
    }
}
```

You can use this static factory method in the `Path` class

```
public class Path
{
    private readonly List<Segment> segments = new List<Segment>();

    public IReadOnlyList<Segment> Segments => segments;

    public Segment AddSegment(int property)
    {
        return Segment.AddToPath(this, property);
    }
}
```

Now it is not possible anymore to create a segment without adding it to a path and without setting the reference to its path.

Comment: By the GoF design-pattern definition, a `factory method` is polymorphic (implemented in a subclass for different types). I see your solution as a `simple factory`? c.f. https://dzone.com/articles/factory-method-vs-simple-factory-1

Comment: I think the correct term for my method is *static factory method*.

Comment: It would be great if you could cite a source for that term. I teach design patterns and factory is perhaps the most overloaded word in that discipline...

Comment: [What are static factory methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods)

Comment: I'd use the [Joshua Bloch reference](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA5&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (see the most-voted answer's comment about why it's not a factory method -- it's essentially the same comment as mine).

Comment: Best answer.  One question / suggestion: why did you name it "AddToPath" instead of "CreateAndAddToPath"?  IMO the later is clearer, but wondering if you have a different take.

Comment: I am not referring to a GoF design-pattern when I say *static factory method*. I just mean a static method that creates, initializes and returns an object.

Comment: `CreateAndAddToPath` is a good name. The name `AddToPath` tells what it does on a higher (geometric) level and ignores the fact that an object must be created (implementation detail). When I review older code that I ‘ve written, I often rename things, because it helps me to understand what a had written. Often when coding I am focused on details, what makes me narrow-minded. Later I often see things clearly. See [The Boy Scout Rule](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Boy_Scout_Rule)

Comment: "Static Factory Method" is a term used by Joshua Bloch in his book "Effective Java", which essentially means `public static MyObj newInstance(){ return MyObj();}`. It has nothing to do with GoF patterns.

Answer (score 7):

It is unclear why segment has to reference a path. It does not strike me as particularly good idea. If it can be avoided - that is what I would refactor to begin with. The problem you are having is a direct result of having a circular dependency, which (in my experience) is never a good thing. I'm afraid there is no pretty way to solve this problem, unless you eliminate the cause.

That being said, if you have to keep the `Path` reference for w/e reason, I think your last option is the best one. I don't quite see why would you need an interface though. As long as `AddSegment(int property)` is the only way to add a segment to path, it does not matter whether or not `Segment` class is public. `Path` class will stay consistent. However I would probably add an overload that takes a segment:

```
public class Path
{
    private readonly List<Segment> segments = new List<Segment>();

    public IReadOnlyList<Segment> Segments => segments;

    public void AddSegment(int property)
    {
        AddSegment(new Segment(property));
    }

    public void AddSegment(Segment segment)
    {
        if (segment.Path != null) throw ...; 
        segment.Path = segment;
        segments.Add(segment);
    }
}

public class Segment
{
    public int Property { get; }

    public Path Path { get; internal set; }

    public Segment(int property)
    {
        Property = property;
    }
}
```

Comment: The bi-directional reference is just like in a graph, where nodes and edges could have references to each other. I wasn't explicit enough about it, but a `Segment` must *always* be a part of a `Path` and therefore I wanted to avoid a  public constructor of `Segment`.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce consistency to a certain degree by making the Segment constructor internal, and putting the Path and Segment classes in a different DLL than your main application code:

```cs
// In one DLL
public class Path
{
    private List<Segment> segments;

    public IEnumerable<Segment> Segments => segments;

    public Segment AddSegment(int property)
    {
        var segment = new Segment(this, property);

        segments.Add(segment);

        return segment;
    }
}

public class Segment
{
    public int Property { get; private set; }
    public Path Path { get; private set; }

    internal Segment(Path path, int property)
    {
        Path = path ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));
        Property = property;
    }
}
```

Then use the Path class in another DLL file:

```cs
// In another DLL

var path = new Path();
var segment1 = path.AddSegment(42);   // Compiles
var segment2 = new Segment(path, 56); // Does not compile. Constructor is internal
```

Because the Segment constructor is marked `internal` you must go through the Path.AddSegment method to create new Segment objects.

**The Segment constructor is free of side effects, because the Path.AddSegment method adds the new segment to the Path's collection.**

Comment: Not a bad idea, but forcing people to move classes between DLLs is quite invasive advice. Usually we don't have a lot of choice in these matters.

Answer (score 0):

If created `Segment` absolutely must be referenced be a `Path`, it reflects some business requirements, and it seems that this requirement constitutes a `Segment`'s invariant. And objects should be created [always valid](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/05/22/always-valid/), with all invariants ensured. Since the code executed while object creation resides in constructor, it's very logical place for enforcing his invariants.

And I agree with Nikita, I'm sure you could avoid that circular dependency. It's considered a [bad practice](https://www.google.com/search?q=ddd%20avoid%20circular%20dependency&oq=ddd%20avoid%20circular%20dependency&aqs=chrome..69i57.2170j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), at least in Domain-driven design.