# If a function mutates outer state during execution but reverts the outer state into original state after execution, does it still contain side effect?

Tags: terminology, side-effect

According to [What is a "side effect?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect), I know the side effect means changing outside world. But what if a function that changes the outside state during execution, but reverts the state to original state after execution? For example, originally I have a function about physics simulation that doesn't modify the outer variable (copy a new data to do simulation):

```
int predictNumberOfStoppedMarbles(std::vector<Marble> marbles){
    //some physics simulation that modifies x,y,vx,vy of marbles but not add,remove marbles or change sequence of marbles
    int count=0;
    for(Marble& marble : marbles){
        count += marble.vx==0 && marble.vy==0?1:0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

However, I found this method is too slow, because it needs to copy all marbles when the function executes, so I modify it as follows, which mutates the exact income data directly:

```
int predictNumberOfStoppedMarbles(std::vector<Marble>& marbles){
    std::vector<std::vector<float> > originalDataArray;
    for(Marble& marble : marbles){ //backup original x,y,vx,vy
        originalDataArray.push_back({marble.x,marble,y,marble.vx,marble.vy});
    }
    //some physics simulation that modifies x,y,vx,vy of marbles but not add,remove marbles or change sequence of marbles
    int count=0;
    for(Marble& marble : marbles){
        count+= marble.vx==0 && marble.vy==0?1:0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<marbles.size();i++){ //restore original x,y,vx,vy
        marbles[i].x=originalDataArray[i][0];
        marbles[i].y=originalDataArray[i][1];
        marbles[i].vx=originalDataArray[i][2];
        marbles[i].vy=originalDataArray[i][3];
    }
    return count;
}
```

now it modifies the outer data source (marbles from outer world) directly during simulation, but after execution, the function reverts the data back. Is the function still considered as "no side effect"?

Note: In real code, the physics engine needs to accept Marble type as parameter, it is not easy to copy or modify the physics logic code that operates from Marble type to float array type, so the solution that modifies the copied array is not suitable for me.

Comment: Doc Brown has answered this perfectly. As a rule of thumb I'd just add that it's usually best to treat "minor side effects" like "side effects", period. Nasty bugs are usually caused by minor errors (major errors would have been noticed much earlier).

Comment: I'm surprised that the second one isn't slower, because you're copying all the marble position data *twice*. However, this is a good example of why game systems sometimes choose "deconstructed" representations where you have "array of X coordinates" and "array of Y coordinates" rather than objects.

Comment: Pjc50 may be right, did you benchmark those two versions? Of course, when a marble object is much larger than those 4 float values, this approach may save a few cycles. Moreover, there was an obvious typo where you confused "=" for "==", I took the freedom to fix it.

Comment: "Side effect" does not only mean changing the outside world.  That's closer to "*visible* side effect" or "observable behavior".  The most appropriate answer to the title question depends to a large degree on why you want to know, because there is a whole cluster of related concepts here and different ones have different implications.  So, why does it matter to you whether either version of your function has side effects?

Comment: @pjc50 : A major reason for game engines to use struct-of-arrays data layouts is so the `marble.vx==0 && marble.vy == 0` condition can SIMD vectorize without shuffles, like load a vector of 4 or 8 VX velocity components and another vector of 4 or 8 VYs, compare each against zero and AND the compare results together.  Then accumulate the 0 / -1 (0xFFFFFFFF) compare results with an integer subtract into a count vector.  Like x86 `vcmpeqps ymm1, ymm0, [rdi]` / `vcmpeqps ymm2, ymm0, [rsi]` / `vpandd ymm1, ymm2` / `vpsubd ymm7, ymm1`.  (Then horizontal sum the count vector after the loop.)

Comment: If you had 4-element marble structs like the OP is making, you'd need some shuffles after comparing both the VY and VX components within one vector.  Or a 64-bit SIMD integer compare to check that both the FP compare results were `-1` instead of `0`.  But half of your vector width is then wasted on elements you didn't need, X and Y components, and `vpcmpeqq` 64-bit integer compare makes a vector with the result from 1 marble instead of from 4 marbles with `vpand`.  Perhaps shuffle together multiple vectors before that step, but that's still more work, and auto-vectorization probably won't.

Comment: Oh wait, this isn't a std::vector of structs, this is a std::vector of `std::vector<float>`, so each element of the outer std::vector is three pointers to dynamically allocated space for four floats.  That's hilariously inefficient, like 24 bytes of pointers and a dynamic allocation for every 16 bytes of floats.  Or instead of a struct, you could just have a flat `std::vector<float>` as the outer array, and use `i*4 + 0..3` to access the components of marble `i`.

Comment: Or even better, have the physics code modify the copy of the x,y,vx,vy components and then discard them.  (It can read `marbles[i]` for the unchanging parts of the marble data so you don't have to copy it all if there's stuff like colour, radius, mass or density, elasticity, spin, etc.)  That would avoid the entire problem of a temporary side effect as well as reducing copying.

Comment: Note that function calls are typically implemented using a call stack, so any function call has the temporary side-effect of modifying the call stack.

Comment: @Stef if you want to be pedantic, then sure everything runs on a machine whose state is mutated all the time and so there's no such thing as a function without side-effects (temporary or otherwise). But that's not a good perspective, it needlessly dispenses with the useful concept of purity. If the low-level state is managed by the compiler and inaccessible from within the language, then the compiler can ensure the mutation will not influence the program semantics, i.e. the side effects are impossible to observe and so for all relevant purposes it may be said that there are no side effects.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The second half of your comment is interesting, but starting with "if you want to be pedantic" then continuing with a slippery-slope argument serves no purpose except deriding my words. Please don't, thank you.

Comment: @Stef well, maybe that phrase was unnecessarily harsh. But the point is, there is a clear-cut distinction to be made between side effects that the programmer is responsible for, and ones that happen behind the scenes set up by the compiler. There is no slippery slope here, but rather a perfectly grippy slope that leads to a vertical cliff.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It's not just behind the scenes. And there are stack-based languages which make the stack very explicit. I thought it was an interesting point. You think it's just an occasion to have an argument out of nowhere.  To each their own. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, at least it is a **temporary side effect**.

You may notice the difference to the fully side-effect free version when you run your program in a multi-threaded context.
Since your case involves performance optimization, I think it is not unlikely you want to utilize multiple threads. Now imagine another thread trying to read data from the `marbles` vector in parallel while `predictNumberOfStoppedMarbles` is executing.

Good luck with debugging such a program!

Of course, from a practical point of view, in a single-threaded context, you can treat the optimized version of `predictNumberOfStoppedMarbles` as if it has no side-effect - when you are 100% sure all exceptions inside the physics simulation are caught (thanks to @GregBurkhardt pointing out that exceptions can cause trouble here).

As an alternative, why not use a combination of your two approaches, like

```cpp
int predictNumberOfStoppedMarbles(const std::vector<Marble>& marbles){
    std::vector<std::vector<float> > workArray;
    for(Marble& marble : marbles){
       workArray.push_back({marble.x,marble,y,marble.vx,marble.vy});
    }
    // some physics simulation that modifies x,y,vx,vy inside workArray,
    // but leaves marbles unchanged !!!
    int count=0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<workArray.size();i++){
        count+= workArray[2]==0 && workArray[3]==0 ?1:0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

*(For the sake of simplicity, I omitted introducing a struct for x,y,vx,vy, but I guess you get the idea).*

Comment: Even a single-threaded context can get unpredictable. What if `predictNumberOfStoppedMarbles` throws an exception before it can revert its changes? What if, due to some defect, it exits before reverting data? What if `count` overflows? Oh boy, would I *not* want to debug that program. JavaScript is single-threaded yet asynchronous. I know the question references C++, but asynchronous callbacks and events can take even the most obvious-looking single-threaded code down some dark, dark corridors.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: indeed.  Thanks for the hint, I took the freedom to include a remark nto my answer.

Comment: Even when the process is single threaded, a temporary side effect on external data will bite you when the process happens to be killed unaware. By the OOM-killer, for instance. That's why it's generally good practice to never modify a file, but instead write the new state to a temporary file, and then overwrite the files' directory entry in an atomic syscall.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: "What if there's a defect" is not a reasonable approach in C++. Defective code can have Undefined Behavior, and then all bets are off. No amount of defensive programming can deal with that. Defensive C++ code protects against defective input, that's doable.

Comment: @MSalters: the code can have perfectly defined and predictable behavior, except the programmer misread it or mistyped it — an unintentional error in logic by the human, not the compiler. Unless you were referring to "defect" in a different sense?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: If I have two containers `v1` and `v2`, and I mistype the iterator range `v1.begin(), v2.end()`, then the result is Undefined Behavior. No amount of defensive programming can fix that.

Comment: What about `if (foo)` when I meant to type `if (!foo)`? I'm not trying to completely negate your point — it's a good one — but there are careless mistakes people can make for which behavior is well-defined. Tracking down those sorts of silly defects in code like this question can become a nightmare. That was my only point.

Comment: And if the vector is in ROM ...

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica: what you wrote is correct, however, I don't think this question was about external data.

Comment: @DocBrown Full ACK. I just think that this is also worth keeping in mind, so I added the comment.

Answer (score 5):

**It is not side effect free anymore.**

Even if you try to cleanup the "temporary modifications", it is a visible side effect. You may get away with it in some situations, of course, but it can cause hard to find concurrency bugs or security issues later.

In fact, if you watched the CPU space, you may have seen the "[SPECTRE](https://spectreattack.com/)" vulnerability being discussed and lots of followups to it. That issue crept into the system exactly due to such a temporary modification of global CPU state that leaked out of the system. The designers thought speculative execution was basically side-effect free, but they were wrong.

So if there is any chance, that your "temporary" modifications may be visible to concurrent or later operations, you can cause trouble and bugs.

Comment: The SPECTRE vulnerability is a perfect "nightmare scenario" for this sort of question.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways the existence of "side effects" can be analysed.

The term is now cemented in the lexicon, and it probably originates from a similar meaning as the term "side channel" (cross-pollinated with the idea in functional programming that function arguments and results are the "main" channel of data flow in functional programs), but it was a poor choice of term because most people already know the word "side effects" from a medical context meaning something adverse and to be avoided, when that is definitely not the case in programming.

In fact, "side effects" in programming - meaning a flow of data occuring other than through function arguments and results - are often the main intended effect of a program, as much as intoxication is the main intended effect of consuming alcohol rather than a side effect of the consumption.

Only disorderly flows of data are undesirable, like alcohol consumption to excess.

That said, a function which changes "outside" data, and then changes it back before its own conclusion, may be interpreted as having "side effects". The question might be whether the effects could be observed - that is, whether any other part of the program (when working normally) could actually read the altered data in the meantime, and whether its execution or results could be affected by it.

There isn't a universal definition of "side effects" that would distinguish the two cases.

It's certainly possible for a function to use non-local storage - that is, storage whose allocation is neither controlled internally by the function nor passed directly as an argument - yet the overall program design could still make it intentionally impossible in practice for there to be any effect outside the function.

However, if you have enough storage and performance available to duplicate the contents of non-local storage, alter it's contents, then set everything back at the end, the real question might be why you don't just operate with the local duplicate, discarding it at the end, and leave the non-local original untouched throughout.

Comment: To your last paragraph - it can often be the case that the storage required for keeping a "backup" of the changed content is much smaller than would be required for taking a complete duplicate: in particular, if only a few fields in each record are modified, or if only a few records out of the whole dataset are modified, then storing only the original values of the modified fields/records is much cheaper than duplicating the whole lot :)

Comment: @psmears, that certainly makes sense.

Comment: "Side effect" is a *general* term, you know, not specific to medical or programming context.  To the limited extent that it has programming-specific meaning, I see every reason to think that that arose as a simple specialization of the well-known term.  Also, in C, at least, "side effects" are not very much about function calls or arguments.  They are effects on the state of the program or its environment produced by evaluating expressions, other than the computation of the result of the expression.  That does include function call expressions, but it's in no way specific to those.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, it's not just the unfortunate conflation with the medical meaning, its the fact that it casts what are often the *main* effects of normal programming techniques as "side effects". Even when talking about evaluating expressions, we are still basically back to dealing with the same mathematical mentality that arguments and results are the main effects, which is usually incorrect (with C's assignment operator itself being an example - the assignment is the main intended effect, the result is the side effect which is only occasionally useful).

Comment: @Steve Result values are not effects at all, main or otherwise. They are mathematically pure, and the mathematical mentality is very useful in reasoning about the results of evaluating an expression. If the evaluation has effects, we need to consider the order of the evaluation and have a more complex mental model for the stateful execution of imperative code. This can account for *side effects* of the expression evaluation, and we use that term regardless whether they are intended or not.

Comment: @Bergi, oh don't get me wrong, I'm not disputing the usefulness of expressions. But I don't think it's very reasonable to describe even a pure function as "having no effect", nor is it reasonable to suggest that most people interpret the word "side" in "side effects" as a supernumerary word. There's no question about the benefit of orderly and simple data flows on reducing the mental burden. The problem is that in any normal industrial application, you would typically expect to find many so-called side effects - and the goal is to properly organise these effects, not to eliminate them. (1/2)

Comment: Also, the point is to teach new practitioners *how* to handle stateful execution, to analyse data flows, and to reason about orders of evaluation and other scheduling concerns - rather than suggest they won't need to. Putting data into storage, and augmenting or overwriting data already stored, is unfortunately one of the most common (and irreducibly essential) activities of programming typical computer applications. (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a good one and it reminded me of an interesting feature of Clojure.  The term used for this (at least in Clojure) is '[Transients](https://clojure.org/reference/transients)':

> *If a tree falls in the woods, does it make a sound?*
>
> *If a pure function mutates some local data in order to produce an immutable return value, is that ok?*

The upshot: this is absolutely done in Clojure and I would consider it one of the more 'pure' functional languages in general use.

I am not a functional programming expert and I am wary of making claims related to it, but I'll hazard a claim that you can do this and still be 'pure' with the caveat that you never leak that state to anything else.  Well, maybe for debugging but nothing else.

Comment: Modification of local data to produce an immutable return value need not be transient.  Something like the string `hashCode` function in Java will permanently mutate one of two fields the first time it is invoked on any particular instance, but calling `hashCode` on a string simultaneously on multiple threads will have no ill effect beyond possibly doing needless work.

Comment: @supercat Are you talking about `transient` variables e.g. in Java?  The term is 'transient**s**' and I don't think it's related.  Maybe check out the link?

Comment: No, I'm talking about lazily computed values which will be written at most once during the lifetime of an object.  A different concept from what the OP is asking about, but another example of the more general concept of internal mutation associated with an externally-immutable interface.

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure how that relates to my answer, but I think you are talking about a type of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Answer (score 0):

If there is any possibility that some other code acts on the temporary modified state then it is a side effect. If it is impossible that some other code acts on it then it is no side effect. For example if a resource is protected by a mutex, or if it is marked as invalid while temporary modified.

Answer (score -1):

Can you guarantee that your current function is the *only* thing touching the data right now? Multithreading exists. Something, someday, may be doing operations on very same data and you just changed the data.
Only if you can guarantee atomicity of the operation, you can consider it side effect free. (Atomicity = until all operations are complete, nothing else can touch the data).
Secondly, you do not guarantee the data to be recovered if exception happens. If something breaks during calculation, the data will be left scrambled.